# how to optimize the following code?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a program in python to replace some values of a data frame, the idea is that I have a file called file.txt and looks like this:

```
A:s:Y:0.1:0.1:0.1:0.2:0.1
B:r:D:0.3:0.5:0.1:0.2:0.2
C:f:C:0.3:0.4:0.2:-0.1:0.4
D:f:C:0.1:0.2:0.1:0.1:0.1
F:f:C:0.1:-0.1:-0.1:0.1:0.1
G:f:C:0.0:-0.1:0.1:0.3:0.4
H:M:D:0.1:0.4:0.1:0.0:0.4
```

and I want to use as separator the ':::', I want to replace the values of the four column for some strings following this rules:

All the values who belong's to the range1 are going to be replaced for 'N':

```
range1=[-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2] -> 'N'
```

All the values who belong to the range2 are going to be replaced for 'L':

```
range2=[-0.5,-0.4,-0.3] -> 'L'
```

All the values who belong to the range3 are going to be replaced with 'H':

```
range3=[0.3,0.4,0.5]
```

In order to achieve this I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=':',header=None)

labels=df[3]


range1=[-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2]

range2=[-0.5,-0.4,-0.3]

range3=[0.3,0.4,0.5]

lookup = {'N': range1, 'L': range2, 'H': range3}




for k, v in lookup.items():
    df.loc[df[3].isin(v), 3] = k


for k, v in lookup.items():
    df.loc[df[4].isin(v), 4] = k


for k, v in lookup.items():
    df.loc[df[5].isin(v), 5] = k

for k, v in lookup.items():
    df.loc[df[6].isin(v), 6] = k

for k, v in lookup.items():
    df.loc[df[7].isin(v), 7] = k


print(df)
```

And it works well but  i want to avoid the usage of so many fors, I would like to appreciate any suggestion of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `where` instead:

```
for k, v in lookup.items():
    df = df.where(~df.isin(v), k)
```

This says to retain the values of `df` when those values are not contained in `v`. Otherwise, replace them with the value `k`. The assignment overwrites `df` at each iteration to accumulate the categorical labels.

This method works on all columns in one operation, so it only works if you want to replace every instance of a given numeric value with its categorical coded letter.

There is another option for `where` that specifies in-place modification, but unfortunately it cannot be used with DataFrames that have mixed column types. In your example, columns 0, 1, and 2 have type `object` while the rest have type `float`. Thus, `pandas` conservatively (and inefficiently) assumes it would have to convert everything to `object` to do the in-place overwrite, and raises a `TypeError` rather than checking further to see if only same-typed columns are actually affected by the mutation.

For example, this:

```
df.where(~df.isin(v), k, inplace=True)
```

will raise `TypeError`.

This limitation with Pandas is fairly frustrating. For example, you also cannot use regular pandas assignment to work around it either, as the following also gives the same `TypeError`:

```
for k, v in lookup.items():
    df.where(~df.isin(v), inplace=True)
    df[df.isnull()] = k # <-- same TypeError
```

and amazingly setting the `try_cast` keyword argument to `True` and/or setting the `raise_on_error` keyword argument to `False` do not affect whether the `TypeError` is raised, so you cannot disable this type safety check when using `where`.

Comment: Thanks for the support, yes my Data Frame contains mixed column types but the first approach that you gave me was very useful, that´s what I was looking for.